# Apache displays some files and does not display others

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, amazon-ec2

I'm getting the strangest problem with Apache installation. I've installed IctFax according to instructions provided [here](http://ictfax.org/content/installation-guide-ictfax-asterisk-18).

I'm now stuck at the point where I've got to configure it. The problem being, that I can access some files in the directory, and I cannot access other files.

Here Is the list of files with permissions for **wwwroot**:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root         19 Aug  6 11:05 ictfax -> /usr/ictfax/wwwroot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         15 Aug  6 11:14 text.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     844795 Aug  6 11:47 tip.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root       4096 Aug  6 11:22 xxx
-rw-r--r-- 1 asterisk asterisk     19 Aug  6 11:30 zz.php
```

and here's the scan for **ictfax** directory:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 asterisk asterisk  4096 Jul 22 07:35 ajax
-rw-rw-r--  1 asterisk asterisk  8770 Jul 22 06:30 astbillupdate.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 asterisk asterisk  8753 Jul 22 06:30 astbillupdatesvn.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 asterisk asterisk 21418 Jul 22 06:30 CHANGELOG.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 asterisk asterisk   749 Jul 22 06:30 cron.php
drwxrwxr-x  2 asterisk asterisk  4096 Jul 22 07:35 database
drwxrwxr-x  5 asterisk asterisk  4096 Jul 22 07:35 files
drwxrwxr-x  2 asterisk asterisk  4096 Jul 22 07:35 includes
-rwxrwxrwx  1 asterisk asterisk   712 Jul 22 06:30 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 asterisk asterisk 10750 Jul 22 06:30 INSTALL.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 asterisk asterisk 18019 Jul 22 06:30 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 asterisk asterisk  1428 Jul 22 06:30 MAINTAINERS.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 asterisk asterisk  4096 Jul 22 07:35 misc
drwxrwxr-x  4 asterisk asterisk  4096 Jul 22 07:35 modules
-rw-rw-r--  1 asterisk asterisk    26 Jul 22 06:30 robots.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 asterisk asterisk  4096 Jul 22 07:35 scripts
drwxrwxr-x  3 asterisk asterisk  4096 Jul 22 07:35 sites
drwxrwxr-x 11 asterisk asterisk  4096 Jul 22 07:35 themes
-rw-rw-r--  1 asterisk asterisk  8867 Jul 22 06:30 update.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 asterisk asterisk     9 Aug  6 11:24 xx.html
```

The server opens [xx.html](http://204.236.158.36/ictfax/xx.html), zz.php, INSTALL.txt, but it does not open index.php or many other files in the catalog.

What could be the problem?
Operating system is Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing, it's been a long time since I worked seriously with Apache.  The example you're giving of a file that does not open is a php file.  The other files in the ictfax directory that you say open are html and text.  zz.php is in a different directory.  It's dangerous to extrapolate from one data point, but are the "many other" files in that directory also php files?

If I remember correctly, Apache configuration for a directory tree does not necessarily apply past symlinks. So it's a possibility that `/usr/ictfax/wwwroot` does not have php enabled even though your main `wwwroot` directory does.  In that case, another `<Directory>` section in your config, enabling php for the `/usr/ictfax/wwwroot` directory, might help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your SeLinux settings, if found enabled then disable it and reboot your system and then try again.

Comment: No need to reboot if you just want to check if SELinux is the root cause for problems. A simple `setenforce 0` will do. If that helps, then modifying `/etc/selinux/config` and disabling SELinux from there is a good idea.